# Turn Variables into Strings

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a login, and will use this for registration, and am allowing symbols and special characters in emails and passwords. I know that this poses a serious threat for hackers with injections. My question is: How might I turn the inputs from fields (ex. 'email', 'password'), into strings and not allow the server to process them as code and commands.

I truly have very little clue as to where to start, but have tried `mysqli_escape_string`; but, as you most likely know, it is very thin and deprecated. I don't mind researching a little, I would just greatly appreciate a bit of information to get started!

Comment: Take a look at PDO -- it makes it a lot easier to work with untrusted input like this.

Comment: @FoxWilson I agree PDO is better but mysqli supports prepared statements too.  Has nothing to do with PDO specifically and PDO queries by themselves add no protection for user inputs.

Comment: Note I'm quite sure `mysqli_escape_string` (`mysqli_real_escape_string`) is not deprecated. Although `mysql_real_escape_string` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use prepared statements when executing mysql queries. (more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php))
2. Limit input field length when possible (normally a mysql injection queries are long. This prevents execution of altered longer queries even there is a vulnerability made by a mistake)
3. Give only the permissions needed for mysql users. Wherever you only need the user to read, provide only read permissions.
4. Encrypt sensitive data like passwords. Use salted password hashing.

Comment: Limiting a password to 10 characters isn't a very good practice.

Comment: Yep. I just wanted to describe what I meant by limiting input field length. I changed it. Thanks.

Comment: i would say don't put a limit to the input password field. More the number of possible permutations and combinations, the more difficult to crack it.

Comment: What is salted password hashing?

Comment: I would seriously caution on building your own login/auth system if you're completely new to it for anything other than a learning exercise. I do NOT recommend doing this for a production/client facing site.

Comment: In normal md5 hashing, the same password is mapped to the same hash value. This is a security risk as if two user use the same password, then their hash value will be the same and an attacker can notice it. An attacker may also observe how hash value changes by encrypting similar strings and calculate the hash function... In salting, each password is appended by adding a random string at the end before encrypting. Therefore none of above is possible.. You may google to find more details..

Comment: You should also note that the hashing of the password and proper sql escaping, is only 1/100th of the details involved in making a proper/scalable/maintainable php web app.

Answer (score 2):

If you really do have no idea where to start, that's not a bad thing! However, I recommend not trying to go create you're own login/registration system unless you do know what to do. Especially if you care about security. This is an extremely easy thing to mess up, even for seasoned programmers. I will be the first to admit, I spent a lot of time rolling my own login/auth modules in PHP, and also spent a lot of time inheriting code where other people implemented their own method, most of the time, improperly.

I recommend learning a web **framework**. My favorite Web frameworks for PHP are [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), and [Code Igniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/), Laravel being my favorite. You'll find that you'll have a learning curve here as well, but you will find a lot more support for implementing user authentication correctly and securely. For exampe: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

With a framework you could also get lots of helper methods to make DB access fun, easy, and safe. Check out the [**examples here**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)! You can always use raw sql if you want!, but for your day-to-day CRUD applications, there is no need!

If you still absolutely insist on doing it yourself, though I will warn you against it one final time. I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements (I prefer PDO).

My guess is that the app isn't too far along since you're still considering how to build login/registration, so you're probably not "stuck" using raw php and doing it all yourself. :)

Comment: If you use a framework, make sure your framework is up to date. Because attackers are trying to exploit frameworks harder. They are more interested on them because if they find a vulnerability, they can exploit all the application which uses the framework..

Comment: Thank you very much for the input! This makes much more sense, actually. The only reason I am working on my own is because I want to be able to say it; but, after reading this, I may use a framework instead for now.

Comment: @plbsam is definitely correct about keeping your framework up-to-date. Fortunately they are regularly updated and far more tested than you'll probably care to do yourself when building your own secure auth system. But I assure you the advantage of ease-of-use and all the tooling makes it worth it. Tooling includes out-of-the-box functionality, pretty urls, db schema mgmt, models, views, controls, deploy scripts, templating, if you want fb/github/google login, there are efficient plugins for it, literally everything you need to build a web-app. When there isn't, you can always do it manually.:)

Comment: Also another major perk is that by knowing main-stream framework well, you can work much faster and build more projects. It also makes you more valuable as a web developer and more likely to be hired. 
For example, If I hire someone to do web work for me, I really really want/need it to be maintainable. That means I want it done in a common framework. It also increases your ability to do consulting by knowing the common frameworks that other companies/people use. 
You can also let other people do the heavy lifting of making a scalable/complete framework/updates. (and also help if you wish)